# HTML AJAX Method not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want a button on HTML to change the content of some page by using AJAX very simple code but when I try to change it simply doesn't work it says:

```
" video.js:20 Failed to load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Rain%20Oficial/texto_prueba.txt: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."
```

Im doing it by a tutorial where it creates at .txt file and makes the page says what the .txt has in it but im trying to replace the .txt file for an HTML tag where I Link a yotube video wth the html youtube tool but even the tutorial example doesnt work video over here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Inicio.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="">
    <title>Rain | Inicio</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header class="main">
        <!--a class="logo-header" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/16/16/32/drop-of-water-1745699_960_720.png"-->
        <span class="site-name"><h1><a href="Inicio.html">rain</a></h1></span>
            <span class="site-desc">Pocos Botones, Dias Memorables</span>
        </a>
      </header>

    <div class="Prin">


        <center><h1 class="titulo">¿Qué es Rain?</h1></center>

        <p class="descrip">Mientras que para acceder a las demás redes sociales o foros, estos requieren ingresar datos personales y completar formularios tediosos, <font color="#5769b4"><b>Rain</b></font> ofrece a sus Usuarios un sistema de foro simplificado y seguro para sus usuarios, no tengan problemas con la privacidad, ni tengan que acostumbrarse a una interfaz complicada, de esta manera es como en nuestra Página Web cumplimos con nuestro lema: <br><br><font color="#365886"><b>Pocos botones,</b></font> <b><font color="#835ebe">Días memorables.</font></b></p>

        <button id="cargar" value="cargar">¿Interesado/a en nuestro video promocional?</button>

    </div>

    <!--Div que funciona cuando el usuario interactue por medio de AJAX-->
    <div class="Prin-video">
    </div>

     <ul class="butt">
            <li><span class="icon-droplet"></span><a href="Formulario.html">Inicia Sesión</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-profile"></span><a href="Registrarse.html">Registrarse</a></li>                    
        </ul>

         <ul class="butt-res">
            <li><span class="icon-droplet"></span><a href="Formulario.html">Inicia Sesión</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-profile"></span><a href="Registrarse.html">Registrarse</a></li>                    
        </ul>

    <script src="js/video.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>




            '/*jslint devel: true */
        var btnCargar = document.getElementById('cargar');


        function cargarContenidoAjax() {
            'use strict';

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


        xhr.open("GET", "texto_prueba.txt", true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            console.log(xhr.readyState);
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                var contenido = document.getElementById('Prin');
                contenido.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }

        };
        xhr.send();
    }



    btnCargar.addEventListener('click', cargarContenidoAjax);'
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8oXTtEsm3k

Comment: you've got javascript ... that isn't inside a script tag - or is that javascript in a separate file?

Comment: I feel obligated to point out the use of the `center` tag which was deprecated even in HTML4, but here used alongside HTML5 tags, and block-level tags inside `spans`. This HTML is really not valid.

Comment: `xhr.open("GET", "texto_prueba.txt"` ... so is the file `texto_prueba.txt` in the same folder as the file containing html you posted? Are you using a web server or is this just a file opened in the browser? which browser? Chrome perhaps?

Comment: Boy im not asking about HTML syntax... "Its not valid" it just works...

Comment: Yeah it is in the same folder.

Comment: Yes im using Chrome.

Comment: and is it through a http server or just opening a file in your operating system?

Comment: I open the file on chrome that's it. no http server.

Comment: Open the browser developer tools console - look for error message, given you are using Chrome, and you do **not** have a http server .... the error is probably to do with **CORS** ... because chrome thinks `file:///` is not same origin as `file:///` because it's stupid ... try **firefox** - it'll probably work- there are some command line settings when running chrome to disable this retarded behaviour, but they are probably dangerous, and a pain to have to use - use firefox, or use a simple http server

Answer (score 0):

Make little changes in your code like

```
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost/Rain Oficial/texto_prueba.txt", true);
```

And it'll work fine